# What action on [action]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I'm not sure what to recommend for the undefined [action](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/action) tag.  The questions all seem to have something in common and "action" is probably the best single word to describe the concept they share.  If this is a useful catchall tag, I'm having trouble with what the definition should be. Maybe:

"Questions involving specific stuff that happens.  If your question involves general stuff that happens, it is off-topic for this tag.  If your question involves stuff that doesn't happen, use the [brick] tag."

Comment: Just burn this one I think. 'Actions' are just Users interacting with [program] IMO, therefore the specific program's tag would suffice

Answer (score 1):

The [action](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/action) in most of the cases is actually is meant in conjunction with [photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) to signify Photoshop Actions. I've removed [action](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/action) and retagged the ones meaning to Photoshop Action to [photoshop-action](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-action).